# Extending nested class lists on item level in Python

Tags: python, list, nested, pickle

I want to set up an updating pickle-file containing 'multiple dataframes'

Therefore I have a list `db_container` that consists of other lists ("the dataframe-category": `alert1, alert2, alert3`) and those include the actual dataframes (e.g. `alert1` has n different dataframes but those have always the same column names)

Now, I have a problem to extend my initial `db` with the new data from `db_container`

My Problem is to extend the `db` on the dataframe level.

After I run my code `db` has 6 Items instead of the inital 3 (alert1, alert2, alert3).

`db` and `db_container`should have always the inital 3 "dataframe categories".

Any suggestions?

```
def pickle_me():

    # Bind Lists of DataFrames into one Object
    db_container = [alert1, alert2, alert3]

    # if a db/pickle already exists then open old one and append with new input
    if os.path.exists(base_path+pickle_db):
       with open(base_path+pickle_db,'rb') as rfp:
          db = pickle.load(rfp)

          db.append(db_container) #-> After this code section db has 6 lists


    pickle.dump(db, open(base_path + pickle_db, 'wb'))

# If no db exists then create one.
else:
    pickle.dump(db_container, open(base_path + pickle_db, 'wb'))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code with `db_container = [1, 2, 3]` and, on the second pass, observed that `db` is `[1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3]]` as I expected. The list doesn't have 6 items: it has 4 items, the last of which is a list with three items. If you intended to add the lists together, you should use `db += db_container` instead of using append, which expects to take a single item.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jim. Ahh I forgot to change my code. I tried with append and extend. Will try your method and will let you know asap. Best Max

Comment: sorry for the late response! It worked perfectly, thanks!